# How to get the value of a content type field in Drupal and pass it to a JS file

Tags: javascript

In my Drupal theme I have a field for soundCloud URL which its machine name is (field_soundcloud_url_) I have a javascript file that will work based of the value of this variable. But it does not work. Here is how I tried to do it:

**page.tpl.php**

```
<?php
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $sound_cloud_url = $node->field_soundcloud_url_['und'][0]['value'];
  drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('sound_cloud_url' => $sound_cloud_url)), 'setting');
?>
```

**JS File**

```
Drupal.settings.my_module.sound_cloud_url
```

Am I doing it correctly? Any idea?

Comment: Looks right to me, except it is usually added in template_preprocess_html(). I would suspect it is added too late through page.tpl.php. Have you checked whether the js file is loaded in the browser?

Comment: @J.Reynolds thanks for your comment but it doesnt work. Maybe the field name isnt correct `field_soundcloud_url_`. To fine it I checked content type and under "MACHINE NAME" its `field_soundcloud_url_`. Is it the correct way of finding it?

Comment: Have you got Devel module installed? add dpm($node); to the code. Also, in your case add the drupal_add_js function via template_preprocess_page().

Comment: @J.Reynolds I have no idea about Devels. But i tired to echo the result in the same page by `<p><?php echo ($sound_cloud_url) ?></p>` but no result. So I think the problem is finding the right filed rather than passing it.

Comment: [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use dpm($SOMEVALUE). That will print things out in a nice click-expandable structure. Also look at [function field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) to access fields the proper way.

Comment: You need to take the call to `drupal_add_js()` out of the template file. It will break as soon as you enable caching/aggregation, which is probably what's happened here

Comment: @Dan how do you get the `$nid`?